# How to combind two xml using wso2 esb

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have tried to combined two xml response into one xml response using following method (playload factory in WSO2ESB) in WSO2ESB. But it returning first xml object only. Please advised me.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <combined1 xmlns="">$1</combined1>
        <combined2 xmlns="">$2</combined2> 
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$env/*[local-name()='Body']/*"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:HotelAmenity/*/jsonArray"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Out put showing like following.

```
<combined1>
      <vh>
            <ho>
               <hn>Excalibur Hotel and Casino</hn>
               <hc>1026</hc>
               <ad>3850 Las Vegas Blvd. South</ad>
               <av/>
               <ci>Las Vegas</ci>
               <co>USA</co>
           </ho>
       </vh>
</combined1>
```

Comment: is it not even showing the combined2 element, or just not the content you want in there?

Comment: Yes, that is my problem. It is not showing here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved this problem using following code.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <main>
          <combined1 xmlns="">$1</combined1>
          <combined2 xmlns="">$2</combined2> 
        </main>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$env/*[local-name()='Body']/*"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:HotelAmenity/*/jsonArray"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Just I have added outer main tag, Now both tag combined1 and combined2 showing and value also showing.

Comment: Is their any way to do this using `<enrich>` tag?